# WCF Address Mismatch Error

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I'm getting this message, when I try to view one of the methods from my wcf service in the browser.

```
The message with To 'http://localhost:55047/Service1.svc/GetMessage' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to an AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. Check that the sender and receiver's EndpointAddresses agree.
```

I have another WCF project that I built on this computer that works just fine and I can successfully view the service methods in the browser.

So I've created a new WCF Service with the following files.

Service Interface

```
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {

        [OperationContract]
        string GetData(int value);

        [OperationContract]
        CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);


        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/GetMessage")]
        string GetMessage();

        // TODO: Add your service operations here
    }
```

Service Implementation

```
public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public string GetData(int value)
        {
            return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
        }

        public string GetMessage()
        {
            return "Hello from the Get Message Method";
        }


        public CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite)
        {
            if (composite == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("composite");
            }
            if (composite.BoolValue)
            {
                composite.StringValue += "Suffix";
            }
            return composite;
        }
    }
```

Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="TestService.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="TestService.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="">

        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Ive looked this up and I havent found anything to solve this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try removing OperationContract attribute and just leave the WebGet. Having both is redundant and may be causing the conflict.

Comment: @Crowcoder I tried your suggestion and edited the post accordingly. I'm still receiving the same error. I read another article about also needing an endPoint configuration in my web.Config but not sure if this is the cause of the problem. Could it be a configuration in IIS that I need to adjust?

Comment: I really can't be sure. WCF configuration can be a bear. Only other suggestion would be to assign a name to your behavior and put that name in the endpoint behaviorConfiguration attribute instead of ""

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, pretty basic but hopefully this will help anyone who runs into this in the future.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="DummyService.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="">
        <endpoint
          address=""
          binding="webHttpBinding"
          contract="DummyService.IService1"
          behaviorConfiguration="Web">


        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Web">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

under the service endpoint adding the behaviorConfiguration="Web" and then the endpoint behavior "Web" is what fixed the problem.